# Octopus gem is sending 2 SQL queries for every ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, octopus

Currently I have a "State" model and following config details in shards.yml.
I am checking the following in "development" environment.

```
octopus:
  environments:
    - development
    - staging
    - production
  replicated: true
  fully_replicated: true 
  development:
    slave1:
      host: 192.168.5.130
      adapter: mysql2
      database: mydb
      username: user
      password: Password
      reconnect: false
  staging:
    slave1:
      host: 192.168.1.2
      adapter: mysql2
      database: server_db
      username: admin
      password: fake_staging_password
      reconnect: false
  production:
    slave1:
      host: 192.168.1.5
      adapter: mysql2
      database: production_db_name
      username: admin
      password: fake_production_password
      reconnect: true
```

When ever I issue State.all or any active record query, I see the same SQL statment is sent to server 2 times

For example State.count sends the following SQL two times.

```
[Shard: slave1]   (1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `states`
[Shard: slave1]   (2.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `states`
 => 35
```

Is this normal? or I have any issue in settings?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're supposed to place either `replicated: true` or `fully_replicated: true`

Not both.